# Python exec script definitions is in db postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql

if a have simple script all is OK. I want to copy 2 characters from 2 columns to the first

```
script = ''' 
b = dff.iloc[:,0] 
dff.iloc[:,1] += b.str[:2]
'''
exec(script)
print(dff)
```

| Nagłówek 2 | Nagłówek 2.2 | CCC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | AA | 23.0 |
| Iza | IzaIz | 4.0 |

But if I have the definitions of the script in the database do not want to start, there is no error!

```
for param in paramdb:
    script = str(param[5])
    print(script)
    print(type(script))
    print(len(script))

    exec(script)
    print(dff)
```

'''
b = dff.iloc[:,0]
dff.iloc[:,1] += b.str[:2]
'''
<class 'str'>
54

| Nagłówek 2 | Nagłówek 2.2 | CCC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA |  | 23.0 |
| Iza | Iza | 4.0 |

Comment: Are the `'''` contained in the database? If so, the script only consists of a string literal which does nothing when executed.

Comment: Yes in db is all, 
'''
b = dff.iloc[:,0]
dff.iloc[:,1] += b.str[:2]
'''
How to do it. Definition was in db and you could run it with EXEC (Script)?

Comment: Just write the script again to db without the triple quotes at beginning and end.